# python - Nothing happens after opening

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyqt4

Today I installed the PyQt4 Designer on my OpenSuse.

If I create a file, run `pyuic4 test.ui > test_ui.py`
it creates a new file.

Now the problem:
If I want to run the code, nothing happens. I opened it with `python3 test_ui.py`

The code of the test-script is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# !/usr/bin/env python
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(473, 316)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 301))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.pushButton.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Button", None))
```

Other scripts like `print("Hello world!")` work. I think the reason is PyQt4.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Piinthesky print("Hello world!") works

Comment: Execute: `pyuic4 test.ui -o test_ui.py -x`

Comment: Unlike a function, a class needs you to instancies, that is, you create an object of that class, and in your case you have not done so, the `-x` option generates a main where it creates the object.

Comment: Please read the PyQt4 Docs: [Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html).